# How can I see the console output on linux like in windows?

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal

Well, let's say we have a application that runs in a console and is for both windows and linux.
On windows when you double click the application a command window opens and the application runs, you see errors warnings etc in the console window and everything it does cout/print/whatever. On linux however when I run the terminal and do ./application_name I don't see any messages/couts/prints? How can I see them? It's really important for debugging purposes.

It's for SA-MP server.

Comment: There's no way of knowing until you tell us what program you're trying to run.

Comment: the program is samp03svr from sa-mp.com

Comment: wow really nice just because I need to know something I do not know i got immeadiately downvoted... nice 'summer of love'... :(

Comment: Sorry, it will not let me remove the downvote until you edit your post. Strange but true.

Comment: Your question was just missing a very important detail, since what you describe is by no means default behavior. That'd explain the down vote, because it would have been impossible to give you an answer. Try not to take it personally :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Linux_Server) says that the Linux version of the SA-MP server does not normally output anything; only in case of errors will there be output.

Comment: and there is no way around it :x okay then I'll have to stick to running the server, closing it, opening the log file, and rerunning debug ;x

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:

```
journalctl -u your_service_name -f
```

Example:

```
journalctl -u origin-person -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a relatively old question, but you can use the following linux command to view the server log:

```
tail -f server_log.txt
```

The `-f` parameter indicates that you want to 'follow' the file's growth. You can stop following the file by pressing CTRL+C.

(This answer assumes that you're `cd`'d to your SA-MP server's root directory)

If you have a separate terminal open with this `tail` command being run, it will track the log between restarts/closes/crashes.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).